# Convert byte to character string

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to convert a byte to a string. The byte(s) are revieved from a bluetooth packet and separated into an array. The data is good but it show the integer value of the received data but I need to show a charature. IE value shows a 65 but I need "A" character for a textview.

The first 10 bytes in the encodedBytes sent to bluetooth {ABCDEFGHI} and the logcat shows 6566676869707172730

```
        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[160];
        System.arraycopy(readBuf, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);


            Log.d("TAG", "Tiles data   ");
            strArrayTitle[0]="";                    // clear


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          // get first 10 chars
              Byte piece = (encodedBytes[i]);
              strArrayTitle[0] = strArrayTitle[0] +(piece);

            }

            Log.d("TAG", "String Data     " + strArrayTitle[0]);

        }
```

I made some changes as per answer and made some progress. I changed the new byte to 10 and converted to string. Can I parse the data so I can convert all 160 bytes at one time ?

```
        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[10];
        System.arraycopy(readBuf, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);

        String title = new String(encodedBytes);

            Log.d("TAG", "Tiles data   " + title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making a string like this

```
String title = new String(strArrayTitle);
```

Where strArrayTitle is a byte[];

Comment: No good, I think it needs to be converted to ACIII. something like byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16");

Comment: I applied your suggestion and made progress, see edits.

Comment: Hitch,thank you for the comment it lead me to a solution. I posted answer

Comment: Awesome, i'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem. I divided the readbuf into sections and then converted to strings.

```
        String[] Titled = new String[16];
        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[10];


        for (int f=0;f < 5;f++) {

            System.arraycopy(readBuf, (f * 10), encodedBytes, 0,  10);
            Titled[f] = new String(encodedBytes);
            Log.d("TAG", "F1  " + f);
        }


            Log.d("TAG", "Tiles data 1  " + Titled[0]);
            Log.d("TAG", "Tiles data 2  " + Titled[1]);
            Log.d("TAG", "Tiles data 3  " + Titled[3]);
            Log.d("TAG", "Tiles data 4  " + Titled[4]);


        }
```

Comment: what exactly is the point in File.read that reads bytes anyway?